# highlighting row entries in an email generated by SQL+HTML script

Tags: html, css

I am using SQL+HTML script to send an email containing columns of a table `mytable`. The table has only 3 rows.  The third row is the difference of first 2 row and hence I want to highlight it (with some background color). I came across `nth-child()` selector but somehow it is not working in my case.

```
SET @tableHTML = 
N'<style type="text/css">

#box-table
{
font-family: "Arial", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
background: #007336;
border: 1px solid #000000;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;
}

#box-table td
{
font-size: 12px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
color: #000000;
padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;
}
</style>'+  
----------Overview
N'<table id="box-table" >' +
N'<tr><th>Order Date</th>
<th>System</th>
<th>SKU Count</th>
<th>OUTL $</th>
<th>OH $</th>
</tr>' +

CAST ( ( 
SELECT td = Order_date,'',
td = System,'',
"td/@align" = 'right', td = SKU_Count,'',
"td/@align" = 'right', td = OUTL_$,'',
"td/@align" = 'right', td = OH_$
FROM #mytable
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table><br/>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients='abc@abc.com',
@subject = NULL,
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Comment: Please use tags properly. This is a pure HTML/CSS question. it is not related to SQL.

Comment: Most HTML email requires you to inline the CSS